# Why do I only get full Internet speed when passing Ethernet cabling through a UPS?

Tags: networking

I've got a really interesting issue. I've got a 200/100 MBit internet connection, which completely worked before. Now, with having the ethernet cabling passing through a UPS (APC Back-UPS ES 700G; also used for surge-protection), I get 100/100 - which is normal for its 100Mbit interface. Recently I tried to test it without the UPS, I only get 15-20/100 MBit.

Now before you start asking for replacing the cables/etc., I want to emphasize the fact that I get the 100 Mbit down with the UPS but *not without*. Connection type directly is 1 Gbps, with pass-thru is 100 Mbit.

Here's a drawing for a better explanation; the lines are CAT5E cables and the cable that goes into the PC directly is the same I use when passing through the UPS:

[image]

I've tried rebooting, trying different operating systems, rebooting the router before I finally found out that it works only properly with the UPS.

Has anyone seen such an issue before, and have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: Yes, CAT5E ones.

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: I've added it, but it's probably irrelevant since I get a slowdown *without* it.

Comment: It might be acting as a repeater/amplifier for the Ethernet signal.

Comment: Could you use a different PC/USB to Ethernet adapter?

Comment: How are you measuring this speed?

Comment: TheKB: There's no USB involved at all.
CharlieRB: Through http://speedtest.net, multiple servers.

Comment: Is the UPS connected to the same port on your switch/router compared to the standalone setup? Have you tried inhouse speedtests as compared to Internet ones?

Comment: @exec this question is now over 2 years old.  How did you get on?  What did you discover?  Feel free to add your own answer and accept it - SE specifically permits this.